# Converting couple of characters from nvarchar to int

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

```
declare @var1 nvarchar(100)
set @var1='C85,c84,c88'
set @var1=REPLACE(@var1,'C','')
select column24 from someTable where column23 in (@var1)
```

Hello guys and gurls, I am new around here and I need help with this. This query gives me nothing I know its beacouse var1 is nvarchar but i dont know how to make it work. Dont ask me why I used that REPLACE, I am testing something, in this particular query it looks stupid. So close your eyes on that one :)
And yes, there are rows 84,85,88 in someTable at column23. I am doing this only thru mssql management studio.

Comment: What is the datatype of your column23

Comment: Its int but i can add another column that i can make varchar and update it with int column values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
DECLARE @var1 NVARCHAR(100);
SET @var1 = N'C85,c84,c88';
SET @var1 = REPLACE(@var1,'C','');

--select @var1;
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(4000);
SET @SQL = N'select column24 from someTable where column23 in (' + @var1 + ')' ;
--SELECT @SQL; 
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: Thanks very much, but there's only one problem, EXEC @sql; wont work beacouse @sql is not stored procedure :D But I can do it with exec (@sql); :)

Comment: My mistake I was in a hurry. I have edited the question!

Comment: Nice to be of help! Can you please accept my answer as the correct one?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
DECLARE @var1 NVARCHAR(100)

SET @var1 = 'C85,c84,c88'
SET @var1 = REPLACE(@var1, 'C', '')

SELECT column24
FROM someTable s
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM (
            SELECT CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE(@var1, ',', '</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x
            ) t
        CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData') m(n)
        WHERE s.column23 = LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]', 'int')))
        )
```